# Why do I need to fetch twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-cursor

I have these lines of SQL:

```
begin
    declare @eid int;

    declare cursor_emp cursor for 
    select id from employee2;

    /*open the dam curson*/
    open cursor_emp;

    fetch next from cursor_emp  into @eid;

    /*0 =The FETCH statement was successful.*/
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
    begin

        if (@eid %2 =0)
        begin
            print ('This one is even!');
        end;

        /* I don't know why the repeating line necessary*/
        fetch next from cursor_emp  into @eid;
    end;

    close cursor_emp;
    deallocate cursor_emp
end
```

It works fine just fine. It's supposed to check whether or not the id is even. I don't understand why I need the line twice

```
/* I don't know why the repeating line necessary*/
fetch next from cursor_emp  into @eid;
```

Within the loop (while), If I remove the line then myloop goes forever! Why the repetition.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor at all is the better question here.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that  first `fetch` pull all records from the column already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `FETCH` is to fetch the first value before `WHILE`. The second `FETCH` inside the `WHILE` fetches as long as the previous fetch succeeds.

See this example from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-fetch-in-a-simple-cursor):

```
OPEN contact_cursor;  

-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  
   FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  
END  

CLOSE contact_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor;
```

But you can also solve this using a simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN id % 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isEven 
FROM employee2
```

Answer (score 1):

A while loops continues till an exit condition is reached. In this case the loop should exit when there is no more records to be processed.

Therefore

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
begin
     if (@eid %2 =0)
     begin
          print ('This one is even!');
     end;
    /* I don't know why the repeating line necessary*/
    fetch next from cursor_emp  into @eid;
    --Fetch is needed to proceed with the next record in order to check if its even and finally exit when there are no more any records left to be processed
 end;
```